# tar: Removing leading `/' from member names "it is not duplicate"

Tags: linux, tar

```
#!/bin/bash

source="/home/user/work/tar/deneme"
source2="/home/user/work/tar/deneme1"
for i in {1..5}
do
        tar -czvf $source2/$i/$i.tar.gz $source/$i/
done
```

I get this error message.

`tar: Removing leading`/' from member names`

this is my script and error. there are a lot of questions here but my problem doesn't solve. I run script than script create .tar.gz file. But if I unzip with `tar -xzvf 1.tar.gz`this command, my file created in full path like `home/user/work/tar/deneme/1/1-1.txt`.

Do you have any idea?

I try some of ways. 
For examle
*[Find /SED to convert absolute path to relative path within a single line tar statement for crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641269/find-sed-to-convert-absolute-path-to-relative-path-within-a-single-line-tar-sta)*
*https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59243/tar-removing-leading-from-member-names/59244*

Comment: So did you add `-C "$source"` or tried `-P` as suggested in the posts you linked? What did it resulted in? `Do you have any idea?` - please be specific, idea about? What exactly is your question? What do you _want_ to achieve? `my file created in full path` and you want your file to be created with what path? Or this is expected and you want them with full path?

Comment: I try `-C "$source"` but again same result. my codes create .tar.gz file but my files created under full path when i unzip tar.gz file.

for example
`/home/user/work/tar/deneme1/1/home/user/work/tar/deneme/1/1-1.txt`


i want my files extracted in current directory.

Comment: So you want to store `./1/1.tar.gz` in the tar? with `tar -tvf` you can list entries in a tar.

Comment: it isn't work.

when I use `tar -zcvf $source2/$i/$i.tar.gz $source/$i`
`
i get this warning
`tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/home/user/work/tar/deneme/1/
/home/user/work/tar/deneme/1/1-1.txt
/home/user/work/tar/deneme/1/1.txt`

then i unzip 1.taz.gz file, my files in 
`/home/user/work/tar/deneme1/1/home/user/work/tar/deneme/1`

Answer (score 0):

This is because GNU `tar` remove leading `/` (by default). To avoid it you can rewrite your script on this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/work/tar
source="deneme"
source2="deneme1"
for i in {1..5}
do
         mkdir -p ${source2}/${i}
        tar -czvf ${source2}/${i}/${i}.tar.gz ${source}/${i}/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your comments and answer.

I find the solution. I change some of codes. which is inside for loop

```
mkdir $source2/$i
cd $source/
tar -czvf $source2/$i/$i.tar.gz $i/*
```